# Activity / intent filter for a specific API level

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an application that contains an activity that is spawned by an intent filter (in this case *android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED*), what it should do (and does) is the following : when the application in question isn't running and the user attaches an USB device that matches the applications filter (e.g. attached device matches the type the application supports), a popup will appear requesting my application (or others with a similar filter) to be opened.

However: I only want this popup to appear/behaviour to occur on Android devices that are of a specific build version (for instance : only run this activity on Android M and above, not for Android API levels 5 or lower).

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the activity itself be available only on certain API levels, create a `boolean` resource, with different values tied to different API levels. For example, you could create a `res/values/bools.xml` file, defining a `boolean` resource, with a name of `is_honeycomb`, and a value of `false`. You could then create a `res/values-v11/bools.xml` file, defining another `boolean` resource, with the same name (`is_honeycomb`), and a value of `true`. The more complex your scenario (e.g., "I only want API levels that are prime numbers"), the more editions of your resource you may need to define.

Then, on the `<activity>` element have `android:enabled="@bool/is_honeycomb"` (substituting in your chosen resource name), and it will only be enabled on the API levels for which the resource is `true`.

Alas, `<intent-filter>` does not have `android:enabled`. You might be able to work around that by using an `<activity-alias>` for your sometimes-available `<intent-filter>`, then enable/disable that alias, though I don't think I have tried this.

Comment: Works beautifully, exactly what I was looking for, and as a solution it's quite elegant as it can be configured using the resource configurations. Thanks!